# Automating validation for website

Tags: ruby, validation, automation, automated-tests

We have a website (which has login, other operations and logout).
Every week, we have a scheduled maintainance on this site. After maintainace, we need to login and click on each and every tabs/menu and see each page loads properly and data is manipulated properly. Is there any way to automate this rather than manual checking everytime.

Comment: take a look at [Capybara](http://jnicklas.github.io/capybara/)

Comment: Things like Capybara or PhantomJS will help

Comment: Your question is too broad. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Answer (score 0):

Use Capybara and `#screenshot_and_save_page`. Name each screenshot with the page name.

Then you can browse the screenshots folder to see all the images. I suggest writing a "script" to show all the images on an HTML page, because it makes it quick and easy to see them all.

[Save Screenshot Reference](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#custom-screenshot-filename)